# how to configure iis 5.1 to allow only localhost or 127.0.0.1?

Tags: iis

In our company iis 5.1 in developer's machine(windows xp) is configured in such way that it will not accept any requests other than localhost or 127.0.0.1. That means if I have a default.htm in page in the root, I can only access this as http://localhost/default.htm or http://127.0.0.1/default.htm. If access this site as http:///default.htm, I will get http 403.6 IP address rejected error. I understnd this is done so that websites in a developer machine cannot be accessed from any other machine with in the company.

I would like to know how to configure IIS5.1 like this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Who tagged this to belong on Super User? If anything, it belongs on Server Fault.

Answer (score 3):

Change the IP of the default binding of the website from "*" to "127.0.0.1". Since localhost resolves to 127.0.0.1, it's also covered.

Answer (score 0):

Right click the website you are configuring. Go to properties, and open the directory security tab. There is a section called IP address and domain name restrictions. Click Edit. Change the 'By default, allow all computers will be: Granted Access to Denied Access. then, add 127.0.0.1 to the Except the following: list.